# JS: The result does disappear after printing out into the screen using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Why is the result appearing as it should but inmediately disappearing?

```js
function conversorMonedas() {
  var pesos = document.getElementById("pesos");
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = pesos.value;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="" onsubmit="conversorMonedas()">
  $ <input type="text" id="pesos" value=""/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Now, If I add a value into the text input and then click the button, that value gets printed on the screen, and inmediately disappears.
On the snippet it does work as intended, but when trying in Chrome, the result does disappear. The console won't show any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're submitting the form after changing the innerhtml
`return false;` instead

```js
function conversorMonedas() {
 var pesos = document.getElementById("pesos");
 document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = pesos.value;
        return false;
}
```

```html
  <form id="form1" action="" onsubmit="return conversorMonedas()">
     $ <input type="text" id="pesos" value=""><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
  <p id="resultado"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've added the return, and it still disappears. But if I change the onclick event handler to onmouseover, it does stay...

Comment: You're welcome. I forget a return on the `onsubmit` also needed.

Comment: Worked like a charm! THANKS!!

Comment: Another way is `onsubmit="conversorMonedas(); return false;"`

Comment: Using `return conversorMonedas();` is useful if the function needs to decide whether to allow the submission or not.